# Error while querying registry remotely

Tags: windows, registry

I am trying to understand the reason why I cannot query a registry remotely. 
I started REMOTEREGISTRY service on both the machines but still I get an error saying **The network path was not found**.
Whereas I can get the result from the other machine.
EDIT: Moreover when I run a SC query for this machine, I get an error **The RPC server is unavailable.**

Comment: Is the "other machine" the one you are trying to access remotely? In which case have you checked the appropriate protocols are not being blocked in a firewall?

Comment: The firewall is taken over by the same Antivirus in all 3 machines. It is strange that even if firewall maybe blocking, but some machines respond to query.

Comment: I just disabled the firewall in PC and still no joy. I disabled IDS and Network firewall too in antivirus. I can't even establish a **net use** session. Though I can run an SC query successfully to check services remotely.